# how to prevent html encoding(special chars) in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have saved some html code in a my database ( using laravel 5.7 , Sqlite )
it saved but after that i want to show it , laravel encodes the special chars.

it have to return as a JSON string to angular without any encoding or changes.

I just want to prevent html special chars encoding.

I have tried this :

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$content = html_entity_decode($post->content);

return ['content' => $content ];
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: How are you accessing it on the blade?

Comment: use `{!!  !!}` instead `{{  }}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your controller

```
1 $post = Post::find($id);
2 $content =$post->content;
3 return redirect('/your-url')->with(['content'=>$content);
```

to return json

```
3. return response()->json($content);
```

in your blade file (please make sure that your file is saved with file-name.blade.php)
you can just output content like thus

```
{!! $content !!}
```

Comment: thanks , i'm trying to find a way that doesn't use blade . and directly in my controller .

Comment: because $content will returns to ajax request directly

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode () to decode and htmlspecialchars() to encode

Answer (score 2):

Simply use built-in `e(...)` helper-function, like:

```php
$myPlainText = e($myUserInput);
```

It probably has the smallest name I have ever seen, but does far more than `htmlspecialchars(...)` function, see:

```php
if (! function_exists('e')) {
    /**
     * Encode HTML special characters in a string.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferringDisplayableValue|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable|string  $value
     * @param  bool  $doubleEncode
     * @return string
     */
    function e($value, $doubleEncode = true)
    {
        if ($value instanceof DeferringDisplayableValue) {
            $value = $value->resolveDisplayableValue();
        }

        if ($value instanceof Htmlable) {
            return $value->toHtml();
        }

        return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i tried this :

```
$post = new Post ;
...
$post->content = htmlspecialchars($request->content) ;
$post->save() ;
```

And then , I used htmlspecialchars_decode() for decoding post's content :

```
$post = Post::find($request->id) ;
$content = htmlspecialchars_decode($post->content);

return response()->json(['title'=>$post->title , 'content'=> $content]);
```

It works.
Thanks for helping ...